# Unpack numpy array shape for general arrays

Tags: python, numpy

An example:

```
    >>> import numpy as np    
    >>> list = [1,2,3,4]
    >>> array = np.asarray(list)
    >>> np.shape(array)
    (4,)
```

Now say I want to process a general array and read the number of rows and columns into variables `m` and `n` respectively, I would do:

```
>>> m, n = np.shape(array)
```

But this results in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

for the example above. In my example above I would have thought `m=1` and `n = 4` would instead have been an appropriate result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array has ndim=1, which means `len(array.shape)==1`. Thus, you cannot unpack the `shape` tuple as if it were of length==2.

To "stretch" your array to have 2dim in case it currently has fewer, use [`np.atleast_2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html).

```
>>> x = np.arange(3.0)
>>> y = np.atleast_2d(x)
>>> y
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.]])
>>> m, n = y.shape
```

BTW, `list` and `array` are not good names for variables in python.

Comment: This makes `m, n` the wrong way around. `m` is the number of rows and `n` is the number of features. `atleast_2d` will give you `(1, m)` given a 1d array.

Answer (score 3):

You showed us that:

```
>>> np.shape(array)
    (4,)
```

that is, it is a single element tuple.

```
m, n = (4,)
```

produces the same error.  There is one element in the tuple, so Python can only unpack it into 1 variable.  This isn't a `numpy` issue.  When doing this kind of unpacking, the numer of variables has to match the number of terms in the tuple (or list).

If you come from  MATLAB you may expect all arrays to be 2d or larger.  But in numpy, arrays can be 1d or even 0d (with shape `()`).  There are multiple of ensuring that your array has 2 dimensions - `reshape`, extra `[]`, `[None,...]`, `np.atleast_2d`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because numpy handle this array as `1D array` and `np.shape` returns the value of shape of this `1D array`, which is a `tuple` with a single element.
Thus we can alter it to a `2D array` with adding [ ] like `[[1,2,3,4]]`.

You can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np    

list = [[1,2,3,4]]
array = np.asarray(list)
print np.shape(array)
m, n = np.shape(array)
print m,n
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 4)
1 4
```

Alternatively you can do this too:

```
import numpy as np    

list = [1,2,3,4]
list = [list]
array = np.asarray(list)
print np.shape(array)
m, n = np.shape(array)
print m,n
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 4)
1 4
```

I hope, it helps.

And yes, you should avoid using the names `list` and `array` as variable name in Python.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why the extra [ ] makes the difference?

Comment: Because numpy handle the array as 1D array and np.shape return the value of shape of this 1D array, when add [], we made a 2D array.

Comment: Great, that makes sense - +1 for your effort and good explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I am happy to help you. However, you didn't accept this as the answer. :)